# item.map Property map is not avabile on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to use the `map` function to loop over every item in an array. But I am getting a TypeScript error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ item: Item[]; }'.ts(2339)
```

Here's my code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import React from "react";
import localStyles from "./../page.module.css";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

/*interface IFetchITems {
  id: number;
  items: any;
}*/

const fetchItems = async (slug: string) => {
 const items = prisma.restaurant.findUnique ({
    where: {
      slug
    },
    select: {
      item: true
    }
  })

    return items
};

export default async function MenuCard({slug}: {slug: string}) {
  const item = await fetchItems(slug);
  console.log(item);
  return (
    <div className={localStyles.menuItems}>
      {item && item.map((item) => (
        <div className={localStyles.menuCard} key={item.id}>
          <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          <p>A well done steak with lobster and rice</p>
          <b>80.00</b>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm using a Next 13 server component with TypeScript.

Comment: Looks like what you're calling `item` is not an array. It's an object with a `item` property, whose associated value is an array. Looks like you want to do `{item?.item && item.item.map(...)}`